# Problem on wagmi safe connector SDK

Tags: gnosis-safe, wagmi, safe-apps-sdk

I am getting an error while confirming the transaction by gnosis wallet ... it works perfectly fine while confirming transactions with another wallet like metamask...
I am using Wagmi, and currently, they have updated their version in which they support Bigint, not Bignumber
the error I encountered while providing an allowance
error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just opened [an issue](https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/2887) on the Wagmi's repo about this problem.

Also, I figured that it can be solved in the meantime by explicitly setting transactions `value` to `0n`.